# PyGame Angle between ball(rect) and rectangle

Tags: python

I'm making a simple game,you know,you move with rectangle at the bottom and you are destroying rectangles at the top with ball what is coming up and down and if you miss the ball you lose..I don't know name of that game..The only one problem is angle,I dont have any idea how to calculate the angle,thanks you a lot!!

Comment: the name of the game could be [Brickout](https://youtu.be/eB9XObmgmhk). Maybe you can beat Woz and do it in 30mins! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can get the angle in radians between any two points with

```
angle_in_rads = Math.atan2(p1.y-p2.y,p1.x-p2.x)
```

this formula should work in pretty much any language (I think pretty much all of them have an equivalent of atan2)

you can easily convert this to degrees if you want (you probably dont want it in degrees)

```
angle_in_deg = angle_in_rads*180/Math.PI
```

for bounce you really dont need to calculate any angles you just need to invert the bounce axis

```
if  rect.p0.x < ball.x < rect.p1.x and ball.y > rect.p0.y:
    ball.vy = ball.vy * -1 # bounce off paddle

if ball.x + ball.vx > game.width or ball.x + ball.vx < 0:
    ball.vx = ball.vx * -1 # bounce off the side walls
```

Comment: what code? I didnt see any code... I see a paragraph with a question about determining the angle

Comment: also what is the purpose of this? if you are really trying to make breakout I might recommend a different framework such as Phaser.IO (its javascript) but it would take very few lines of code to make breakout in phaser.io

Comment: But if I just invert axis,I can get only 2 values,so my ball will move only in 2 directions,or am I wrong? EDIT:Oh I got it,but I dont think that it's the best idea :-) but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean like [Breakout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_(video_game))?

I think [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) is a good place to start, check out their [examples](http://www.pygame.org/tags/example), they even have already some [Breakout clones](http://www.pygame.org/tags/breakout).

If you have the movement vector of the ball, you can calculate the angle with [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) (even a `rotate` method is provided, for calculating how the ball bounces back from the bar the player controls).

Comment: Exactly Breakout :-)) Looks good,I'll check it out..but still I don't have an idea how it should looks(code) :PP

Comment: I suggest you download [Simple Breakout](http://www.pygame.org/project-Simple+Breakout-872-.html) and have a look into the code.

Comment: @phos456 Did it work with looking into the code? Consider chosing an accepted answer if it helped with your question.

Comment: To be honest I've figured it out without looking into the code of that simple Breakout,but I still appreciate your answer! :-))